# C++, порядок инициализации static полей для static объектов

Tags: c++, static, member

У меня есть вопрос, который касается порядка инициализации объектов со статической продолжительностью хранения.

Мне известно, что:

- Статические объекты одной и той же единицы трансляции инициализируются в том же порядке, в котором они определены;
- Статические объекты разных единиц трансляции инициализируются в неопределенном порядке.

Рассмотрим код:

```
class Object
{
    Object()
    {
        // Использование field.
    }
    static const size_t field;
};

Object object;
```

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: возможно ли, что статический объект, который содержит статический член, начнет конструироваться раньше, чем его статическое поле?

То есть, допустим, я хочу дать всем объектам класса `Object` статическое поле, которое является разделяемой константой для всех объектов данного класса.

Но у меня появляются некоторые подозрения...

Comment: какие подозрения, на счет чего подозрения у вас?

Comment: "...является разделяемой константой". Что значит "константой"? Все ваши соображения относятся только к *динамической* инициализации. Вы вашу "константу" как собрались инициализировать? Статической инициализацией? Динамической инициализацией?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сами правильно перечислили правила динамической инициализации статических объектов. Статические поля классов полностью подчиняются эти правилам, т.е. порядок динамической инициализации таких полей определяется тем местом, в котором они *определены* (кроме inline полей).

> Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: возможно ли, что статический объект, который содержит статический член, начнет конструироваться раньше, чем его статическое поле?

Разумеется, может.

В одной единице трансляции, в таком порядке

```
Object object;
std::size_t Object::field = std::rand();
```

согласно правилам, которые вы сами привели, конструктор объекта `object` будет выполнен раньше, чем будет выполнена динамическая инициализация `Object::field`.

---

Вышеприведенные соображения относятся, еще раз, лишь к *динамической* инициализации. Если вы выполните *статическую* инициализацию вашего поля `Object::field`

```
std::size_t Object::field = 42;
```

то она будет выполнена *раньше* любой динамической инициализации, т.е. такое поле будет фактически "уже инициализировано" в момент старта программы, независимо от того, где в программе располагается это определение.

Comment: С порядком в одной единице трансляции я все понял. Что касается разных единиц трансляции: если в классе имеются статические поля, тогда объект такого класса нельзя делать статическим в единицах трансляции, отличных от той, в которой статические поля определены, все верно?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под статической инициализацией поля?

Comment: @MGNeo: Инициализация глобальных объектов в С++ делится на *статическую* и *динамическую*. *Статическая* инициализация - это обнуление статических объектов и инициализация константными инициализаторами и (где применимо) constexpr конструкторами. Статическая инициализация всегда выполняется раньше динамической. В примере выше я специально вызываю функцию `std::rand`, чтобы получить именно динамическую инициализацию. Если бы я написал просто `= 42;`, то это была бы статическая инициализация. Она бы выполнялась раньше конструктора `object`.

Comment: спасибо. Все намного сложнее, чем я думал. Скажите, есть ли гарантированно безопасный способ инициализировать разделяемые константы? Чтобы конструктор статического объекта, использующий такие константы, не привел к неопределенному поведению?

Comment: @MGNeo: Что значит "инициализировать константы"? Ещё раз: все зависит и о того, чем и как вы их инициализируете. Если это скалярный тип, который инициализируется константным значением (`= 42`), то все получается безопасно. Если же инициализатор неконстантен (`= rand()`), то начинаются нюансы.

Comment: у классов бывают свойства, которые являются общими для всех объектов этого класса. Такие свойства обычно делают статическими полями-константами. Проблема в том, что иногда такие поля используются в конструкторах (других классов). И если вдруг такой конструктор будет вызван для статического объекта, то возникнет неопределенное поведение. Надо как-то запомнить, что не следует делать одни статики на основе других...

Comment: Ещё раз: вся система инициализации статических объектов критически опирается на важнейшую фундаментальную гарантию: *статическая* инициализация всегда гарантированно выполнена *заранее*. Поэтому вы должны либо пользоваться статической инициализацией, либо опираться на статическую инициализацию при выполнении динамической.